# cant access remote mysql server need help

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003

I have a unix server with mysql which I am trying to access from my machine. To clarify, access the mysql server. When I do I get this error.

```
Connecting to MySQL server 192.168.1.25...
Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.25' (10061)
```

Here are my credentials:

```
username: root
port: 3306
```

The server is running because I am able to remotely login onto the machine (with ip: 192.168.1.25" and then run mysql from root. What do you think is going on:

1. Is it a firewall issue?
2. Accessing as 'root' is being denied?

I am new to mysql.

Comment: Just to note Access Denied errors are de-noted with an "Access Denied" type error message.  This is a connection issue, that could be my.cnf or network related (firewall, iptables, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because remote root login is not allowed.  You can try this article on how to enable remote root:

http://benrobb.com/2007/01/15/howto-remote-root-access-to-mysql/

Comment: After the last step in the instructions provided in the link you need to restart the mysqld service.

Comment: it is not suggested to allow root to access remotely. Too dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

1)
check the logs
you can see where the logs are by checking the my.cnf file.
mysqld.log might be the file name, but where

2)
a. see if it's a network issue.

```
telnet 192.168.1.25 3306
```

b. see if the service is at that port.
    ssh to the box
    # from the local host
    mysql -u root 
    telnet 127.0.0.1 3306

```
ps auxw|grep mysql
```

you should hopefully have enough diagnostic info at this point to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

i have this problem and fix it by

first you must grant all to user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename. TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and change the mysql config using

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

find "**bind-address**" row and comment it.
save config and restart mysql using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

hope solve problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The Message (10061) is do to offline severs or firewall blockage
If you get -the name of your pc - can not connect, then mysql is rejecting the connection and you will have to create a 'user' in the mysql database `mysql`, table `user` using the IP of the remote connection', and restart the database service

but for error 10061 check The Firewall in both machines. 
Masters PC per say, is the one with the phpmyadmin installation

Allow Destination ip-[the remote] and port 3306 on the Master Machine 
and
Allow source ip-[the masters]/with any port, and check your destination port(3306) too. destination ip can also be set on some firewalls.

And if you can, search in your firewall for logs, settings, recent activity, etc... to see what and how you are being blocked.