# Connecting Remotely to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having trouble connecting remotely as well as connecting using my IP rather than "localhost" to my MySQL server.

What have I done to try and solve this problem?

- Opened the port 3306 on TCP and UDP.
- Added a port exception in the Windows Firewall.
- Allowed MySQL public connections through the Windows Firewall.
- Also made a user which I granted all privileges for and flushed them afterwards.

I want to use my C# application to connect to this database and retrieve the data through a datagridview (currently working flawlessly through localhost DB).

What am I missing here to get my connection to work so I don't end up with this error?

> Failed to Connect To MySQL... (10061)

I have only tested the connection on the same PC if that matters, which I believe shouldn't since it's the same IP?

Working local connection string:

```
string connString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=myUser;password=myPassword";
```

Comment: This question is not Off-Topic, developers need to know how to connect to MySQL all the time.

Comment: "as well as connecting using my IP" - Is MySQL restricted to listening on localhost only? Try `netstat -an |grep 3306` - you want it to say `0.0.0.0:3306` not `127.0.0.1:3306`. And then you'll need to make sure that your database user account's host is `%` not just `localhost` else it won't be able to log in, or create a separate user for remote access.

Comment: Confirming that the account host is "%".
Where can I bring up the console for the commands? I only have MySQL Workbench installed regarding databases.

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply. netstat is command for the Windows command prompt, not MySQL Workbench. If you get an error trying to pass the output into grep, use `|more` instead and just look for the TCP LISTEN 3306 line.

Comment: I found the adress, and it's 0.0.0.0:3306.
I'm thinking of starting a new thread regarding getting data from a google Spreadsheet using Google API soon. Never gotten MySql to work other than locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to your IP you should port-forward your router.

There are a lot of guides at http://portforward.com/

Comment: Edit: I've seen you did portforward. Can you show us the code where you connect? Maybe your DSN isn't valid.

Comment: Edited my top post. I have the main connection added on through a Data Source on my wForms App. If you need any more code, I can add the rest, but it's just the command to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

check that your mysql port is accessible from the internet, for ex test using: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Is your mysql accepting remote connections ?

see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6687959/3882707

Comment: "Port 3306 is open." so the port is fine.